# handle get request in controller action

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-gateway

In a custom payement gateway, where the store redirects to third party website for payment. To request i have options to send either in POST/GET. I'm requesting with POST method. But the response they give is in get method.

The response url according to their documentation is `http://yoursite.com/success?q=su&oid=XYZ1234&amt=100&refId=000AE01`

And in my case i have captured response at `http://yoursite.com/cgateway/payment/response` with `responseAction` method of `PaymentController.php` controller.

The result i obtained is `http://yoursite.com/cgateway/payment/response?q=su&oid=XYZ1234&amt=100&refId=000AE01`

Now the problem is how should i get those data in `responseAction` in PaymentController ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get params in a controller you can use:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('paramName');
```

or

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Answer (score 2):

Magento's default routing algorithm uses **three part** URLs.

```
http://example.com/front-name/controller-name/action-method
```

So when you call

```
http://example.com/path/action/id/123
```

The word `path` is your front name, `action` is your controller name, and `id` is your action method.  **After** these three methods, you can use `getParam` to grab a key/value pair

```
http://yoursite.com/cgateway/payment/response?q=su&oid=XYZ1234&amt=100&refId=000AE01

//in a controller
var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams('q'));
```

You may also use the `getParams` method to grab an array of parameters

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Hope this helps